# Angular 2 Property Does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I have a Class Like

```
export class R {
constructor(
    public id: Number,
    public dte: Date,
    ) { }
```

}

a service That return R[] the code is like :`

```
return this.http.get(this.serverLocal).map(this.formatDate);

  formatDate(res: Response) {
    const data = res.json() as R[];
        data.forEach(D => {
        D.dte = new Date(D.dte);
    })
    return data;
}
```

I get the 2 errors: property 'dte' does not exist on type 'R'.
I changed a lot of code for no avail. It's working if I do some change with ID, but not with dte date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you log data ?

Comment: Yeah the service is working correctly and I get 450 records

Comment: can you replicate this issue in stackblitz

Comment: It's a long procedure, the class has more field etc, but the error is coming only with the DTE. without the DTE Code I can debug my code and even execute the R.Dte = new Date(R.Dte) manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering, take a look at [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) if you are using Angular 5 as `json()` is no more needed. An http get already returns a json by default.

If your json response has only these two entries (`id` and `dte`) you simply have to do the following:

```
. . .

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/** rxjs **/
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

getStuff(someUrl: string): Observable<Array<R>> {
    return this.http.get(someUrl);
}
```

If you need some error handling or, for instance, retry if the request gives error your should do something like:

```
. . .

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

/** rxjs **/
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

getStuff(someUrl: string): Observable<Array<R>> {
    return this.http.get(someUrl)
        .pipe(
            retryWhen(errors =>
                // Do Stuff
            ),
            catchError((error: Error)  => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })
        );
}
```

There is no actual need of mapping data, but, if you would like to do it, you should do like":

```
data.map((dataEntry) => new R(dataEntry))
```

If you are still using Angular 4.x.x, you should get it going with:

```
. . .

import { Http } from '@angular/http';

/** rxjs **/
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

getStuff(someUrl: string): Observable<Array<R>> {
    return this.http.get(someUrl)
        .pipe(
            map((response: Response) => response.json()),
            catchError((error: Error)  => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            })
        );
}
```